# What displays work with the Mac Pro (2019)?

Tags: display, mac-pro, thunderbolt-display, compatibility

What displays *besides* the [Pro Display XDR](https://www.apple.com/pro-display-xdr/) will work with the [2019 Mac Pro](https://www.apple.com/mac-pro/)? Is there a list somewhere of (both Apple and non-Apple) displays that are compatible?

[image: 2019 Mac Pro]

Comment: It's Thunderbolt 3, so presumably anything you can get a TB3 adaptor for.

Comment: It might be several months premature to know what drivers will be included in a not released software for not released hardware. I'm sure lots of people can speculate based on pre-release hardware and pre-release software and assumptions based on ports shown which are unlikely to change. Mind if we put this on hold unless there's a practical question to be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Mac Pro can be configured with a range of graphics card options.

Regardless of the option chosen by the user, it can be connected either via HDMI 2 or Thunderbolt 3 to compatible displays, and also provides the option for DisplayPort connections<sup>*</sup>.

The various graphic card options also provide different combinations of these ports. For example, the base level AMD Radeon Pro 580X comes with two HDMI 2 ports and four DisplayPort connections that can support the following combinations of external displays:

- six 4K displays
- two 5K displays
- two Pro Display XDRs

The AMD Radeon Pro Vega II, on the other hand, comes with one HDMI 2 port, four Thunderbolt 3 ports, and two DisplayPort connections that can support the following combinations of external displays:

- six 4K displays
- three 5K displays
- two Pro Display XDRs

And finally, the AMD Radeon Pro Vega II Duo comes with one HDMI 2 port, four Thunderbolt 3 ports, and four DisplayPort connections that can support the following combinations of external displays:

- eight 4K displays
- four 5K displays
- four Pro Display XDRs

Of course, with the expandability of the Mac Pro you also have the ability to use different graphics cards and therefore the types of displays compatible with it will depend on the card you're using.

Finally, with the use of adaptors you may be able to support other displays as well.

<sup>* DisplayPort connections are routed to the system to support internal Thunderbolt 3 ports</sup>